# Archer shoots 2 times. He gets as many more goes as he hit the target. Find the probability of him hitting the target exactly k times.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Archer shoots 2 times. He gets as many more goes as he hit the target. Probability of him hitting the target is q=0.4.Find the probability of him hitting the target exactly k times.

My solution

Hi - archer hits i out of 2 in the first go

Ak - hit the target exactly k times

P(Ak) = P(Ak-2)P(H2) - P(Ak-1)P(H1)

I got a complicated recurrence equation so i am not sure if this is correct

Pk = 0.16 Pk-2  +  0.48 Pk-1

Comment: Say you shoot two times first and get one right. So you get one more chance to shoot? Whether you get a fourth chance, depends only on third shoot? If so, you get to only one chance at a time the moment you miss one out of two at any point.

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there are *two* targets and the archer shoots at each target repeatedly until he misses. Then the probabilities of getting $k$ hits are easily seen to be equal to those of the original problem.

Using the revised formulation, the probability of getting $k$ hits is that of getting exactly one miss in $k+1$ attempts and then a second miss, for a final answer of
$$(k+1)(0.6)^2(0.4)^k$$
This is, in fact, a [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).